# Error Compiling Armadillo

Tags: c++, armadillo

I have the following error trying to compile Armadillo:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_wrapper_ddot_", referenced from:
      void arma::syrk_vec<true, false, false>::apply<double, arma::Mat<double> >(arma::Mat<double>&, arma::Mat<double> const&, double, double) in exampleArma.o
      void arma::syrk_vec<true, false, false>::apply<double, arma::Row<double> >(arma::Mat<double>&, arma::Row<double> const&, double, double) in exampleArma.o
  "_wrapper_dgemm_", referenced from:
      void arma::gemm<true, false, false, false>::apply_blas_type<double, arma::Mat<double>, arma::Mat<double> >(arma::Mat<double>&, arma::Mat<double> const&, arma::Mat<double> const&, double, double) in exampleArma.o
      void arma::gemm<true, false, false, false>::apply_blas_type<double, arma::Row<double>, arma::Row<double> >(arma::Mat<double>&, arma::Row<double> const&, arma::Row<double> const&, double, double) in exampleArma.o
  "_wrapper_dgemv_", referenced from:
      void arma::glue_times::apply<double, true, false, false, arma::Mat<double>, arma::Mat<double> >(arma::Mat<double>&, arma::Mat<double> const&, arma::Mat<double> const&, double) in exampleArma.o
      void arma::glue_times::apply<double, true, false, false, arma::Row<double>, arma::Row<double> >(arma::Mat<double>&, arma::Row<double> const&, arma::Row<double> const&, double) in exampleArma.o
  "_wrapper_dsyrk_", referenced from:
      void arma::syrk<true, false, false>::apply_blas_type<double, arma::Mat<double> >(arma::Mat<double>&, arma::Mat<double> const&, double, double) in exampleArma.o
      void arma::syrk<true, false, false>::apply_blas_type<double, arma::Row<double> >(arma::Mat<double>&, arma::Row<double> const&, double, double) in exampleArma.o
```

I'm compiling using makefile and i already tried the solutions found here with no good results. Until now my project has different classes that are compiled with makefile. Two of them use armadillo: the first one doesn't show any problems. Instead this new class gives me compilation errors. I figured out that the error here is given using the `cor` function of armadillo. When i just use rowvec or cx_rowvec as in the first class all works perfectly. Debugging i noticed that when i uncomment the line code with `cor` i get the error. Can someone help me? I installed the last armadillo version 7.600.2.

Now i tried to use different Armadillo library functions: it sounds like i don't have some of them. For example using the following functions `mean(X),var(X),stddev(X)` i haven't any problems, it compiles perfectly. Instead when i try to use others function like `cov(X), cor(X)` i get that errors. I guess that i don't have that functions in my library. So in order to solve the problem i tried to remove safely the old library and install a new one. Unfortunately the error holds. I hope this update will be helpful. I don't think that i'm doing some mistake in my makefile, because it doesn't compile well just when i use some specifics functions in my code.
Thank you to everyone!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: See the "linking" section of Armadillo [Frequently Asked Questions](http://arma.sourceforge.net/faq.html) page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved commenting the following lines in armadillo_bits/config.hpp:
`#define ARMA_USE_LAPACK`and `#define ARMA_USE_BLAS`.
Even if it works,  it's the wrong solution. A better solution is described in the linking section here http://arma.sourceforge.net/faq.html#linking.

Comment: This is the wrong. A better solution is described in the "linking" section of Armadillo [Frequently Asked Questions](http://arma.sourceforge.net/faq.html) page.